# BULK API reader with PK chunking enabled : Multiple batches are created in salesforce side with 0 rows processed

Tags: bulk-api

I have object with 100,000 records. And trying to read from Salesforce using PK chunking with 50,000 as chunk size. I expect two batches , each with 50,000 records. but what i noticed is 361 batches created , where many are with 0 Records Processed and few batches with records lesser than 50,000.

Is this the expected behavior from salesforce? Can any explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Is PK chunking  salesforce functionality or a feature on a 3th party tool ? The context of the question isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding after reading [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/03/use-pk-chunking-extract-large-data-sets-salesforce.html) that PK chunking works by splitting all records of specific object into groups with **sequential** SF IDs and only after that it splits them further into batches of a specified maximum size. In your case it just so happens that you have 361 groups of records with **sequential** IDs in your org.

On a related note - are you actually performing selective SOQL query or are you just trying to fetch ALL records from that object? If later, then you should be ok with just using bulk query and batch size of 5K-10K.

Comment: Am doing a simple select statement( no where clause ) to fetch all the records.
even for this does it creates batches with 0 records ?

Comment: @bhargav swargam In PK chunking buckets of 50K(in your case) would be created based on first id and last id present in your org for that sobject. I have observed that sometimes Id creation skips its sequential patter so there comes this huge gap which contributes to bucket but will not have any records. This behaviour is must be because salesforce wants to keep ids unique across all orgs. I am not much sure about it. This is my observation when I tried to implement custom PK chunking for batches.